# How to merge 2 CvRects with minimal distance that are result of cvContour

Tags: opencv, merge, contour

in my project i use cvFindContours to detect objects.
With the result(s), i want to mark the roi of the input image(If the distance between the detected blobs are high i want to iterate the tagging of the roi).

My problem is, that a few  rects from the found blobs are overlapped or is part of a bigger blob.
Is there a fast solution to remove inner blobs and merge blobs with minimal distance?

For example:

Comment: adding an example image is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if rectangles are overlaping using [operator& of cv::Rect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rect#Rect_):

```
cv::Rect a(x1,y1,w1,h1);
cv::Rect b(x2,y2,w2,h2);
cv::Rect intersect = a&b; // if intersect is not empty, the rect overlaps
```

As for your "minimal distance", there is no way to do that using standard opencv functions. You have to determine what is the "distance" between the rectangles: distance between their centers (not recommanded) ? Distance between their borders? Then remind you have 2 dimensions. You can do it, but you have to code it yourself.

Comment: hi, i implemented this in JavaCV. Thx